# How to save attachment to a custom object in salesforce using Java or Android

Tags: custom-object, attachment

I have scenario in which i have to send multiple file from my local file system of the mobile through phonegap and jquery mobile to android which in turn sends the file to the salesforce server to a custom object. Is there any api available for this. Can you anyone explain how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Java solution:

```
package com.claimvantage.ant;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.FilePart;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.MultipartRequestEntity;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.Part;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.PartBase;

public class AttachmentExample {

    private class JsonPart extends PartBase {

        private byte[] bytes;

        public JsonPart(String name, String json) throws IOException {
            super(name, "application/json", "UTF-8", null);
            this.bytes = json.getBytes("UTF-8");
        }

        @Override
        protected void sendData(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
            os.write(bytes);
        }

        @Override
        protected long lengthOfData() throws IOException {
            return bytes.length;
        }
    }

    private String baseUrl;     // Initialization not shown here
    private String sessionId;   // Initialization not shown here

    /**
     * Create attachment SObject from its JSON populating its Body from a file at the same time.
     */
    public void createAttachment(String attachmentJson, File attachmentFile) throws Exception {

        PostMethod post = new PostMethod(baseUrl + "/services/data/v23.0/sobjects/Attachment");
        post.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + sessionId);
        Part[] parts = new Part[] {
                new JsonPart("Json", attachmentJson),
                new FilePart("Body", attachmentFile)
                };
        post.setRequestEntity(new MultipartRequestEntity(parts, post.getParams()));
        try {
            new HttpClient().executeMethod(post);
            if (post.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_CREATED) {
                // Logic for OK
            } else {
                // Error handling logic
            }
        } finally {
            post.releaseConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

taken from my blog post [Creating an Attachment SObject complete with its body using the REST API from Java](http://force201.wordpress.com/2013/05/17/creating-an-attachment-sobject-complete-with-its-body-using-the-rest-api-from-java/).

Comment: i am also following the same code but it displays this error java.net.UnknownHostException: cs7.salesforce.com....i have set proxy also but still same error exist

Comment: @HariniSekar I suggest you ask about this on phonegap or Android forums...

Answer (score 0):

After setting the proxy it works correctly

```
package com.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream; 
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.FilePart;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.MultipartRequestEntity;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.Part;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.PartBase;
import org.jboss.resteasy.util.Base64;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class AttachmentExample {

    private class JsonPart extends PartBase {

        private byte[] bytes;

        public JsonPart(String name, String json) throws IOException {
            super(name, "application/json", "UTF-8", null);
            this.bytes = json.getBytes("UTF-8");
        }

        @Override
        protected void sendData(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
            os.write(bytes);
        }

        @Override
        protected long lengthOfData() throws IOException {
            return bytes.length;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create attachment SObject from its JSON populating its Body from a file at the same time.
     */
    public void createAttachment(String attachmentJson, File attachmentFile) throws Exception {

        PostMethod post = new PostMethod( "https://cs7.salesforce.com/services/data/v24.0/sobjects/Attachment" );// test na14 cs7        

        post.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + "00DM000000147ht!AQMAQHHZ1bOXs.xz4Ogza4.G45BtRHw9GiQvs8QgyR4D1dDir1bjXkrMVkfkKyvFPVp6MsA9tr9Dgn13EVwHgj14sQdNLB2a");
        post.setRequestHeader("sessionId", "00DM000000147ht!AQMAQHHZ1bOXs.xz4Ogza4.G45BtRHw9GiQvs8QgyR4D1dDir1bjXkrMVkfkKyvFPVp6MsA9tr9Dgn13EVwHgj14sQdNLB2a");


        try {

            Part[] parts = new Part[] {
                    new JsonPart("Json", attachmentJson),
                    new FilePart("Body", attachmentFile)
            };

            post.setRequestEntity(new MultipartRequestEntity(parts, post.getParams()));
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.getHostConfiguration().setProxy("138.21.89.90", 3128);

            int status = httpClient.executeMethod(post); 
            String response = post.getResponseBodyAsString();

            System.out.println(" status : " + status);          
            System.out.println("Response Content Length : " + post.getResponseContentLength());         
            System.out.println("response : " + response);            
            System.out.println(" getStatusCode " + post.getStatusCode() + " getStatusText : " + post.getStatusText());

            if (post.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_CREATED) {
                System.out.println("Logic for OK");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error handling logic");
            }

        } finally {
            post.releaseConnection();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try {           
            File f = new File("D:\\Public\\Downloads\\TNPSC012014_401757481.pdf");

            obj.put("name", f.getName());
            obj.put("Description", "Last Modified : " + f.lastModified() );
            //obj.put("ParentId", "a03M0000005MkW1IAK");
            obj.put("ParentId", "a03M0000005MkW1IAK");

            String name = f.getName();           
            int lastIndexOf = name.lastIndexOf(".");

            if (lastIndexOf > -1) {
                obj.put("ContentType", name.substring(lastIndexOf));
            }

            AttachmentExample ob = new AttachmentExample();
            ob.createAttachment(obj.toString(), f);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```